# Appropriate model to test if environmental variable is significant between two species?

Tags: theoretical-biology, biogeography

I want to know if a given environmental variable has an effect on the range of two species/two groups of species. Specifically, I am interested in testing if one species has a "preference" for higher/lower ranges over the other (for example, do blue frogs prefer colder temperatures than red frogs?). I have occurrence data for my species as well as environmental data in a grid over the area. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This question seems like it might be a better fit for the [statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Do you want to test of they have different environmental preferences (in relation to a set of environmental variables), or if there is a positive/negative relationship between their ranges? Your Q seems to have bits of both, but they are not the same thing.